# PostgreSQL migrating from 9.2 to 9.5 with data dir on different volume

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have a problem in upgrading postgresql 9.2 cluster to 9.5 using pg_upgradecluster, because the data directory is on a different volume from the root one.

At the beginning, we just tried:

```
# pg_upgradecluster 9.2 main --method=upgrade --link
```

But it failed because our data directory for 9.2 is on a different volume mounted on /data:

> Could not create hard link between old and new data directories:
>   Invalid cross-device link In link mode the old and new data
>   directories must be on the same file system volume.

Later we found out that we could tell the upgrader to put the new version on the same volume like this:

```
# pg_upgradecluster 9.2 main /data/postgresql/9.5/main --method=upgrade --link
```

This worked on a test installation with the same volumes and directory structure, but it failed when we tried it again in production. This was the output :

> root@myserver ~ # pg_upgradecluster 9.2 main /data/postgresql/9.5/main
>   --method=upgrade --link
>
> Disabling connections to the old cluster during upgrade...
>
> Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
>
> Stopping old cluster... Creating new cluster 9.5/main
>   ...   config /etc/postgresql/9.5/main   data
>
> /data/postgresql/9.5/main   locale en_US.UTF-8   port   5433
>
> Error:
>   **could not symlink configuration file**
>
> Error during cluster dumping,
>   removing new cluster

Searching around it looks like maybe the first attempt at upgrading created these symlinks:

> lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   36 Apr 17 08:32 pg_hba.conf ->
>   /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres
>     38 Apr 17 08:32 pg_ident.conf ->
>   /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_ident.conf lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres
>     40 Apr 17 08:32 postgresql.conf ->
>   /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf

We also found a reference (http://postgresql.nabble.com/Problem-pg-upgradecluster-from-9-1-to-9-3-tp5829359p5829495.html) that suggests it could be an issue with an older version of postgresql-common we have installed - this is the full list of our packages:

> root@myserver ~ # dpkg -l | grep postgres ii  pgdg-keyring
>     2014.1                          all         keyring for apt.postgresql.org rc  postgres-xc                          1.1-2ubuntu2 
>   amd64     write-scalable, synchronous multi-master, transparent
>   PostgreSQL cluster ii  postgresql-9.2
>     9.2.9-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64       object-relational SQL database, version 9.2 server ii  postgresql-9.5
>     9.5.2-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64       object-relational SQL database, version 9.5 server ii  postgresql-client-9.2
>     9.2.9-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64       front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.2 ii  postgresql-client-9.5
>     9.5.2-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64       front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.5 ii  postgresql-client-common          154.pgdg14.04+1
>   all       manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions ii 
>   postgresql-common                 154.pgdg14.04+1                 all 
>     PostgreSQL database-cluster manager ii  postgresql-contrib-9.5
>     9.5.2-1.pgdg14.04+1             amd64       additional facilities for PostgreSQL ii  postgresql-server-dev-9.2          9.2.14-1.pgdg14.04+1 
>   amd64     development files for PostgreSQL 9.2 server-side programming
>   ii  postgresql-server-dev-9.5         9.5.2-1.pgdg14.04+1
>   amd64     development files for PostgreSQL 9.5 server-side programming

So the question is:

- Should we upgrade postgresql-common using

  # sudo apt-get install postgresql-common=173.pgdg15.10+1

? Is it safe even if we still have 9.2 running?

- Should we also manually delete the symlinks

> pg_hba.conf -> /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf pg_ident.conf ->
>   /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_ident.conf postgresql.conf ->
>   /etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf

Or the latest version of postgresql-common should be able to proceed without that?

Thanks!